# Simulate correlation matrix using a given structure

Tags: correlation, simulation, random-generation, correlation-matrix

I want to generate correlation matrix such that it follows the below structure $$\Sigma = B \Lambda B^T $$

where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing positive elements, $\Sigma \in R^{n \times n}$ is a correlation matrix and $B \in R^{n \times k}$ where $k$ is less than $n$. Here each column of $B$ is a sparse column with a certain sparsity $\lambda$ and $B$ is not necessarily orthogonal matrix. I am not sure how to generate a correlation matrix given above structure.

Comment: Are you sure that the diagonal elements of $B \Lambda B^T$ = 1? Which one $B$ or $|Lambda$ needs to be simulated?

Comment: @a_statistician I need to generate both $B$ and $\Lambda$. Yes, the diagonal elements should be 1 such that the final matrix generated is a correlation matrix.

Comment: Is $k$ an input?