# How to simulate random correlation matrix containing off diagonal structures

Tags: correlation, matrix, random-generation, correlation-matrix

I want to simulate a correlation matrix which has some off-diagonal structures and also should have some hierarchical structures. For simulating correlation matrices which contain hierarchical structures, I am using [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5834.pdf). But, I don't know how to add off-diagonal structures to it.
I want to simulate a correlation matrix which somewhat have off-diagonal structures as below image

[image]

An example of a hierarchical structure in the correlation matrix is below image
[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to simulate such correlation matrices?

Comment: Dunno if this is helpful, but with [mvnorm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164471/generating-a-simulated-dataset-from-a-correlation-matrix-with-means-and-standard/164476) in R you can generate data for whatever correlation matrix you want. But I'm guessing you don't want to sit there typing out each individual element in that matrix. Oh well, hope this helps a little anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate correlation matrix using a given structure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376097/simulate-correlation-matrix-using-a-given-structure)

Comment: If you can translate "hierarchical structure" to "eigenvalue structure" (clumpiness), see [scipy.stats.random_correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.random_correlation.html).  Or, generate `R' Λ R` with random orthonormal `R` in a language of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this paper: [CorrGAN: Sampling Realistic Financial Correlation Matrices Using Generative Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.09504.pdf)

The idea is to use a Generative Adversarial Network to learn the empirical structure in your matrices. Then, one is able to sample from this empirical distribution of correlation matrices.

For example, output of the model trained on financial correlation matrices (correlations between S&P 500 stocks returns):
[image: example of model output]

You can find an example how to use such model here, [on this Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S9qIFOGQZwHAR5-Jqm_u_EuQ2ebRidi-?usp=sharing).